# How to get the date of a certain week's day?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using Excel 2010.

If I have `TODAY()` function on a cell (`cell2`), it gives me this: `12/26/2012`. I want to get Monday's date based on `cell2` date. In other words, in want this: `12/24/2012`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it (although I don't have Excel handy so taking it from memory)

```
=A1-WEEKDAY(A1, 3)
```

(where A1 is the cell containing the date)

Answer (score 0):

```
=A1-(WEEKDAY(A1)-2)
```

Where A1 is today's date. This formula will return the Monday date of the week `today()` is in.

Or:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A1)>2,A1-(WEEKDAY(A1)-2),A1-(WEEKDAY(A1)-2)-7)
```

if you want the previous Monday's date.